# How can we localise Angular 13 library?

Tags: javascript, localization, internationalization, angular-library, angular13

We have a web components library developed in Angular 13. We want to add translations support to library however @angular/localize package does not seems to support Angular library **("projectType": "library")**.

What's the best approach to add localisation support to **angular 13 library**.